# Animate jQuery scrolltop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have a scrollTop function in jQuery but I can't animate it. Is it possible?

```
$(".loadmore").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("up-arrow", 1000);
  $(window).scrollTop($('.docs').offset().top, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.animate()`?  `.scrollTop` doesn't take a duration argument. [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `animate()` for this.

Example code applied on a `div` is as follows :

```
//Scroll to bottom
$('div').animate({scrollTop: $('div').get(0).scrollHeight}, 3000);

//$('div').get(0).scrollHeight - will give the full height of div.
//scrollTop - will be used to animate from the current position to page end.
//3000 - will be the duration.
```

Demo can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/codebombs/GjXzD/

Comment: Will this give any problem, when we try to scroll while the animation is going on? I am facing such issue, but I have this called in setTimeout(). The scoll seems to get buggy.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.docs').offset().top}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#ID').click(function(){
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
return false;         });
```

Try this code of Jquery