# jQuery: How to animate this scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, overflow, scrolltop

```
$("#wrapper").scrollTop($("#wrapper").scrollTop()+$("div.element.active").position().top);    
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yuFk5/250/

This script includes a workaround to allow scrolling with overflow hidden, but I am getting confused about how to implement animate into this to give the animation a duration.

Comment: [Same as here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800090/animate-jquery-scrolltop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off the code in your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuFk5/461/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#foo").click(function() {
        $("#wrapper").animate({'scrollTop': $("#wrapper").scrollTop()+$("div.element.active").position().top}, 400);    
    })
});
```